# how to add two JTextfields to "north" or i will say similar direction in java

Tags: java, frame, jtextfield

Guys i want to add 2 JTextFields in my calculator.I want to add them to my frame below each another like the windows calculator .

Comment: You should add some code :)

Comment: Don't use `BorderLayout` except for the simplest of cases.

Comment: A `JPanel` with a `BoxLayout`, for example, inside your `JFrame`?

Comment: Use GridLayout to your JPanel

Answer (score 0):

It May Help You To put Your COntrol On North. You May Use JPanel To Put Your Controls in Some Meaningful Manner

```
getContentPane().add(jTextField1, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

For More Information Visit [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_borderlayout.htm)

Comment: Thx guys for ur help